# Having different valid Schemas for one field without using mixed

Tags: mongoose

I have following situation:

```
var aField1 = new Schema({
    //Stuff1
});

var aField2 = new Schema({
    //Stuff2
});

var MainSchema = new Schema({
    aField: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true},
});
```

My questions regaring that:

a) Is it possible to define 'aField1' AND 'aField2' both to valid Schemas for 'aField'? Without using mixed?

b) If yes, is it possible to validate both cases?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not ideal, but maybe you can use [Mongoose Custom Validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) to achieve this, something like:

```
var aField1Schema = new Schema({});
var aField2Schema = new Schema({});

var MainSchema = new Schema({
  aField: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true, validate: models(['aField1', 'aField2'])}
});

mongoose.model('aField1', aField1Schema);
mongoose.model('aField2', aField2Schema);
mongoose.model('Main', MainSchema);

function models(possibleModels) {
  return [function(value) {
    return possibleModels.indexOf(value.constructor.name) === 0;
  }, 'validation of `{PATH}` failed with value `{VALUE}`'];
}
```

then for creating the document, you can do this:

```
var doc = new Main({});
doc.aField = new aField2({});
doc.save();
```